# How to fill events with value, based on value's index in relation to event [pandas]

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Sorry if the title is not clear, this issue i'm having is a little hard to summarize.

I have one column which contains value of an event at it's peak. The non-peak values are just nan.

```
[np.nan, 30, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, 20, np.nan]
```

The second column defines whether we are in event A or B

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Based on the index of the value in relation to what event it falls under, i want to "fill" the events with corresponding values.

```
[30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
```

Since the index of the first 30 value falls under this particular section of event A, we fill that event in with the 30 and so on.

The example is here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [np.nan, 30, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, 20, np.nan],
                   'event': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']})

    val event
1   NaN     A
2  30.0     A
3   NaN     A
4   NaN     A
5  10.0     B
6   NaN     B
7   NaN     A
8  20.0     A
9   NaN     A
```

I want my output column to be `[30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby.apply` :

```
df['output'] = df.groupby(df['event'].shift().ne(df['event']).cumsum())['val']\
                 .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max()))

print(df)
    val event  output
0   NaN     A    30.0
1  30.0     A    30.0
2   NaN     A    30.0
3   NaN     A    30.0
4  10.0     B    10.0
5   NaN     B    10.0
6   NaN     A    20.0
7  20.0     A    20.0
8   NaN     A    20.0
```

Comment: From some initial testing it looks like this is what i need. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway to modify this to do this same thing (take the max of the group) if there are no NaN's?